# How to get all visible running applications package names?

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat, activity-manager, multi-window, split-screen

I have a custom launcher which is always visible and it starts 3 different apps. Starting from Android N on each app icon click (on the custom launcher) I must check whether any of the 3 applications is currently running.

- If no app is running, the clicked icon should start the app normally.
- If any of them is currently running multi window mode must be turned on and show both of them.
- If 2 of them are running, the inactive one (which is in "onPause" state) should be replaced with the third.

How can I determine currently visible all applications like in the screenshot [image: screenshot] to compare with package names of my 3 apps and take respective steps. I tried standard solutions with Activity Manager, however all I got was only Custom Launcher's package name as it became active on icon click.

Comment: getRecentTasks were used for this purpose is Depricated from Api 21.And not available for 3rd party app now. [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getAppTasks()).